# How to assign random numbers to phase value for all noise F-Curves modifiers?

Tags: python, modifiers

I think that the question is pretty straightforward. I been trying to do it by my self for a while but I'm stuck.

This is the script I've made:

```
import bpy
import random

for i in bpy.data.objects:
    i.types.FModifiers.phase = random.random*5
```

... which of course fails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explained in the inline comments:

```
import bpy
from random import random

# Only selected (thus visible), editable objects
# bpy.data.objects would affect all objects in all scenes!
for ob in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:

    # OPTIONAL: Ignore object types other than mesh
    if ob.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    # Is there an animation?
    if ob.animation_data is not None and ob.animation_data.action is not None:
        action = ob.animation_data.action

        # Iterate over all F-Curves
        for fcu in action.fcurves:

            # Iterate over all F-Curve modifiers
            for mod in fcu.modifiers:

                # Only act upon Noise modifiers
                if mod.type == 'NOISE':
                    mod.phase = random() * 5
```